# C++11 condition_variable synchronisation issue

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, stdthread

I have a simple thread pool that needs to be able to wait for its workers to consume all the tasks in the queue without using standard `thread::join()`, as I don't want to kill the threads themselves but just wait for them to complete all the tasks while staying in their execution loops. I thought of accomplishing this using `condition_variable`s, like so:

**ThreadPool.cpp**

```
void ThreadPool::addTask(ThreadTaskFunction task, void *arg) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> t_lock(task_lock);
    tasks.push_back(ThreadTask(task, arg));

    // For every tasks that is added, I increment a counter
    assignedTasks++;
}

void ThreadPool::join() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(join_lock);
    joinCondition.wait(lock, [this](){
        return assignedTasks == 0;
    });
}
```

**Thread.cpp**
Note that this is a friend class to ThreadPool

```
void Thread::threadLoop() {
    while (!shouldDie) {
        ThreadTask task;

        if (pool.hasTasks()) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(pool.task_lock);

                if (!pool.hasTasks()) continue;

                task = pool.getTask();
            }

            task.function(task.argument);
            this->completeTask();
        }
    }

    this->isThreadFinished = true;
}

void Thread::completeTask() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(pool.task_lock);

    // When a task is completed, I decrement the counter and notify the main thread that a task has completed.
    pool.assignedTasks--;    
    pool.joinCondition.notify_one();
}
```

I'm using this thing for a physics simulation, and this stuff happens on every step of said simulation (around once every 16ms). What happens is that after a few hundred steps, everything stops because somehow a notify signal is sent **before** the main thread enters the wait status, probably because it's checking the condition. If I debug, I can see that I have one task left on the counter, no tasks running on the threads, no tasks in the queue and nothing really happening anymore. Sometimes, even weirder, everything unlocks as soon as I pause execution with a breakpoint and restart it. I've tried putting more locks in place to no avail.
Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

**UPDATE** It appears that the problem is solved by setting the `assignedTasks` variable as `volatile`. It's getting modified so often that sometimes the value in the registers is not updated and everything stops. Never had to do this before. Huh. :)

Comment: join doesn't kill threads, it waits for them to finish

Comment: But I don't want them to finish, I just want them to finish their task and then loop on, waiting for more. I want to be able to wait for all current tasks to finish, so that I can schedule some more without having to start new threads but use those I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different mutexes (`join_lock`, `pool.task_lock`) to "protect" `assignedTasks` at different times - this is a plain old-fashioned race condition.

Comment: You are indeed right, using the same lock (task_lock, for instance) solves the problem even without the "volatile" variable. My question is then twofold:
1. Why/how did volatile solve the issue?
2. Why doesn't locking the mutex in the ThreadPool::join() function stop threads from obtaining new tasks in Thread::threadLoop()?

Comment: 1. The semantics of C++ `volatile` is almost entirely implementation-defined. For MSVC, `volatile T` has acquire-release semantics much like a C++11 `std::atomic<T>` (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.110).aspx). 2. Those are the semantics of condition variables: they drop the lock while blocked, and re-acquire it when checking the condition - all "behind the scenes" (See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).